# Does selenium's waits always need a timeout?(Python)

Tags: python, selenium

In selenium [doc](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) we can see that we must set some timeout for wait.
For example: code from that doc

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'someid')))
```

I wonder do we **always** must set up some timeout? Or there is some method that will wait until all of the AJAX code will download and only after it our driver will interact with some web-elements(I mean without any fixed timeout , it just loads all things and only after it starts interacting)?

Comment: you mean like a listener? that knows when the ajax-response has arrived?

Comment: @drkthng yes,something like this

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this code will help you.  This is how I solved this issue.

```
 #Check with jQuery if it has any outstanding ajax
    def ajax_complete(self):
        try:
            return 0 == self.execute_script("return jQuery.active")
        except:
            pass
    #Create a method to wait for ajax to complete
    driver.wait_for_ajax = lambda: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ajax_complete, "")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Comment: this script looks interesting but there we still have some strict timeouts (`lambda: WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`) and `driver.implicitly_wait(30)`.But can we write our code without those "10" , "30" etc.?

Comment: you could theoretically set the value very high and have a long timeout you will never hit.

Comment: well yes that's obvious)But maybe somebody knows a different method (if such does exist )

Comment: I have not done it yet.  I preferred a timeout.  Have you checked any of these?

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html

sorry I am not more help